# want to print Full calendar

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

I am using Jquery Full calendar resource view and I want to print this page .
code that i tried...

```
    <link href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css'
                                         rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
    function print_calendar() 
    {
        window.print();  
    }
```

but it display like this...
[image]

Please give me any solution waiting for positive reply.

Comment: I were using it in one of my projects and had to customize its appearance heavily to fit my needs. I think it's default layout, if you want a nicer layout :), you need to modify fullcalendar.print.css yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put it in Iframe and it works properly. Due to conflict its not display properly.. Thank you  for giving me suggestions. I also edited in fullcalendar.print.css.

```
.fc-event {
   background: #ffffff !important;
   color: #000000 !important;
}

.fc-widget-content {
   border: 1px solid #000000; 
}

.fc-event-bg {
   display: none !important;
}

.fc-event .ui-resizable-handle {
   display: none !important;
}

.fc-header {
   display: none; vertical-align: top; 
}
```

Comment: its great. keep it up

Comment: @sharvari can you post full detail as to how to solved the print issue?

Comment: @Smith I clearly Mention that , I used ifarme html Component it solve my scc conflict and due to ifame its work properly. My css Code is as bellow                                                                     
<code>.fc-event {
 background: #ffffff !important;
 color: #000000 !important;
 `
  

 }
 .fc-widget-content {  /* <td>, usually */
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 }
/* for vertical events */
 
.fc-event-bg {
 display: none !important;
 }
 
.fc-event .ui-resizable-handle {
 display: none !important;
 }
 .fc-header {
 display:  none;
 vertical-align: top;
 }</code>

Answer (score 4):

Try including both stylesheets

```
<link href="fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
```